# OS.File crashes my extension after firefox update from 34 to 35

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm quite new to extension development and the Update from 34 to 35 crashed my extension. The extension is not initializing and running, unless I uncomment line 2 and 3.
I could narrow down the problem to the OS.File which I'm using from the main thread.
I write a simple string to a file, like in the example at [OS.File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread)

My Code:

```js
let encoder = new TextEncoder();
let array = encoder.encode(GTRatio); //global string variable
let promise = OS.File.writeAtomic(filename+".txt", array, {tmpPath: "file.txt.tmp"});   //filename is another defined string
```

Do you have any idea or suggestions? I imported the module with:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm");
```

thx for help

Comment: Can you post the error traceback please?

Answer (score 1):

I had no output in the console, absolutely nothing. But now i used try/catch around and it works sometimes again to write/read the files.
Thx for asking for the stack trace, that's what gave me the idea for try/catch.